# How do I send cookies in a request from an Angular 2+ application to a Django backend where I access them as cookies?

Tags: django, angular, cookies, angular6

Angular sets cookies in the browser, but when I do a POST request to Django, **request.COOKIES is empty in the Django view**. I need to send the CSRF cookie back to Django, stored and accessed as a cookie.

**Note: Simply sending the CSRF in headers as below (or using any other header technique) does not work (Django still logs "Forbidden: CSRF cookie not set")**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedService } from '../../shared.service';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailService {
// http options used for making any writing API calls with csrf token
private httpOptions: any;
csrfToken;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, private cookieService: CookieService) {
  // Set the csrf token
  this.http.get(SharedService.contactEmailUrl).subscribe((data) => (this.csrfToken = data['csrfToken']), (error1) => console.log(error1));
}

sendMailgunContactMessage(payload) {
  // Configure CSRF token header options
  this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-CSRFToken': this.csrfToken,
      'x-csrftoken': this.csrfToken,
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.csrfToken,
      'XSRF-TOKEN': this.csrfToken,
      'X-CSRF': this.csrfToken,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: this.csrfToken,
      csrftoken: this.csrfToken
    }),
    withCredentials: true
  };

  let body = {
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: this.csrfToken,
    content: payload
  };

  this.cookieService.set('csrfcookie', this.csrfToken);
  return this.http.post(SharedService.contactEmailUrl, body, this.httpOptions);
}
}
```

Comment: what cookie do you need to send...csrf?

Comment: Yes, I need to send csrf

Answer (score 0):

If you talking about CSRF to allow your POST to your backend, you can pass it in your headers when you send your data to django

Check this examples:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf-protection.html

Comment: That doesn't work for me (Django still logs "CSRF cookie not set") (see above edits)

Answer (score 0):

to insure that you have the cookie on every request

1. I add ngx-cookie-service to my project https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service#readme
2. Then I make an interceptor csrf.interceptor.ts

```html
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    csrfToken: any;

    constructor(
        private cookieService: CookieService
    ) {
        this.csrfToken = this.cookieService.get('csrftoken');
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this.csrfToken) {
            const addCsrf = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set('X-CSRFToken', this.csrfToken)
            });
            return next.handle(addCsrf);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in your app.module you need to provide the interceptor:

```html
// angular core
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

// services
// components
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [
        CookieService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: CsrfInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It looks like this gets a cookie that was sent from Django and sends a header back to Django, but does not set a cookie accessible as an actual cookie by Django. I wish this was a solution, but I think Django will still complain "CSRF cookie not set".